# Why is Bloomberg showing difference yields than US Dept of Treasury

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bloomberg, bond-yields, treasury

I am using historical 30yr US treasury rates for a project. When I downloaded the rates from Bloomberg by queuing the history of the USGG30YR index, I found the numbers different from what US Department of Treasury has.

A few examples:

[image: USGG30YR on Bloomberg]

https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2023

The 30yr "mid-yield" on Bloomberg for USGG30YR is 3.8410 on 2/15/2023.
The "par-yield" on Dept of Treasury on the same day for 30yr is 3.85.

The 30yr mid-yield on Bloomberg for USGG30YR is 3.7746 on 2/14/2023.
The par-yield on Dept of Treasury on the same day for 30yr is 3.81.

I have some thoughts that I'd like to get checked. Please let me know if anything I say is not right.

1. I think it might come down to the definition to par-yield. Par-yields are mathematically derived, while Bloomberg uses market data.
2. Since par-yields are mathematically derived, it does not account for trading costs, liquidity, inefficiency and so forth, while Bloomberg market data naturally reflects all forces.
3. For above two reasons I feel Bloomberg USGG30YR is a better representation of 30yr Treasury yield.

Comment: Treasury par yields are derived from indicative, bid-side market price quotations obtained by the Federal Reserve Bank of New York at or near 3:30 PM each trading day. They are also constant maturity (interpolated). I am not next to a terminal ATM but think the GGR (generic bonds tickers) actually reflect the on the run bond (almost never exactly the quoted tenor). In any case, you look at mid on HP and the yields (also computed from indicative quotes using the generic source BGN) are from a different time (should be 5pm New York). Overall, neither of your points is true.

Comment: @AKdemy Thanks for your input.